# All radiobuttons are checked c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with my 3 radiobuttons in c# at Visual Studio 2012 - when i run this application in browser and check first radiobutton, then check second the both of them are marked.

```
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked) 
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
            TextBox1.Text = "";             
        }
        else if (RadioButton2.Checked) 
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
        else if (RadioButton3.Checked) 
        {
            ListBox3.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);             
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            ListBox2.Items.Clear();
            ListBox3.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="195px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="32px" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
            <br />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="123px" Width="126px"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Height="123px" Width="126px"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" Height="123px" Width="126px"></asp:ListBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click"  />
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you set the GroupName attribute of the radiobuttons to the same value ( a name for that group of radio buttons).

eg:

```
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio1" Text="something" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio2" Text="another thing" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton id="Radio3" Text="something else" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: yep.  in asp.net, radio buttons must be in the same group unless you use a radio button list control instead of a radio button control.